# Symfony2 allow a FOS user to only update entities they have a relation to

Tags: symfony, doctrine, crud, fosuserbundle

I want to limit my user account to only view and modify entities it has a relationship with.

I've got a basic FOS User setup, and I have a entity with a one to many relationship with my user entity.

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="blog")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $user_id;
```

The schema validates properly, and doctrine seems happy with my relationship.

I've used the **app/console generate:doctrine:crud** command to generate a basic crud system.

How should I limit doctrine from returning entities that don't have a relationship with the logged in user?

This is the code I'm currently using to get all entities.

```
$entities = $em->getRepository('ExampleBundle:Blog')->findAll();
```

Is there a pre-built command for fetching by user id, or do I need to write some DQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `findBy` method with the current logged in user.

```
$user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
$entities = $em->getRepository('ExampleBundle:Blog')->findBy(array('user' => $user));
```

And in your `Blog` entity, it's not a `user_id` but a `user`, you want to get the user not the id. `$blog->getUser();`

Hope it's helpful.

Best regard.

Comment: Thanks that does exactly what I needed. I believe your first line should have "$this->get" instead of "get" on it however.